# macTex 2018 arara misssing lmkclean script

Tags: mactex, arara, cleanup

I use arara to build and that worked well with 2017 MacTex and TexShop but since i have updated to 2018 version of MacTex i get a error in the line: `% arara: lmkclean`  that sounds like this: `I could not find a rule named 'lmkclean' in the provided rule
paths. Perhaps a misspelled word? I was looking for a file named
'lmkclean.yaml' in the following paths in order of priority:
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules)`
copying the file from the old 2017 distribution directoy to the 2018 directory prints this error:

```
I have spotted an error in rule 'lmkclean' located at
'/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules'. I could
not parse the rule, something bad happened. Apparently, the
provided YAML file is invalid. I will do my best to help you in
any way I can. There are more details available on this
exception:

DETAILS ---------------------------------------------------------
Cannot create property=command for
JavaBean=com.github.cereda.arara.model.Rule@4c1d9d4b
in
'reader', line 1, column 1:
    !config
    ^
Unable to find
property 'command' on class: com.github.cereda.arara.model.Rule

in 'reader', line 7, column 10:
    command: <arara> latexmk
@{include} "@{file}"
```

i can do this:

```
% arara: clean: {extensions: [aux,log,bib,bbl,blg,glg,glo,gls,idx,ilg,ind,ist,lot,out,xml,toc]}
```

but that seams a bit odd to me, and it does not work for sub directories.
is there a way to clean automaticaly all tempfiles as well in subdfolders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Version] [image: Status] [image: Documented]

Version 4.0 of `arara` merged all rules related to `latexmk` into a single rule. In order to clean all temporary files generated after a sequence of intermediate calls for document generation, you need to provide a `clean` parameter in the directive. Possible values are:

- `all`: This value, as the name indicates, removes all temporary, intermediate files, as well as resulting, final formats such as PostScript and Portable Document File. Only relevant source files are kept.
- `partial`: This value, as the name indicates, removes all temporary, intermediate files and keeps the resulting, final formats such as PostScript and Portable Document File.

Sample usage:

```
% arara: latexmk: { clean: partial }
```

It is worth mentioning that this parameter has higher priority over other parameters. The user manual contains a comprehensive list of all parameters available for the `latexmk` rule.

Hope it helps. `:)`